# TypeError: $(".ajax-fc-container").captcha is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, captcha, typeerror

I'm having problem with captcha (http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin). I'm getting error like in the title. Anyboby know what's the problem?

The "obj" has "captxt and "array" field.
I'm including `jquery-1.5.1.min.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` library
This is a sample from my JS code:

```
function loadlang(lang) {
    var rand = $.ajax({ url: '/captcha/data.aspx', async: false }).responseText;
    var obj = eval(rand)[0];

    $(".red").removeClass('red');

    $(function () {
        $(".ajax-fc-container").captcha({
            borderColor: "silver",
            text: obj['captxt'],
            items: obj['array']
        });
    });
    $("#resend_password_link").html(obj['resend_password_link']);
    $("#sectxt").html(obj['sectxt']);
    $("#more").html(obj['more']);
    $("#langtxt").html(obj['langtxt']);
    $("#optionstxt").html(obj['optionstxt']);

    $("#submit").val(obj['Login']);
    $("#tab").hide();

    $("#desc").html(obj['Text']);
    $("#dialog").html(obj['Browser']);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    //InitLang();
    var lang = document.location.href.split('lang=')[1] || 'pl';
    loadlang(lang);

    $("#lang").remove();
    $("#myForm").append("<input id=\"lang\" type=\"hidden\" style=\"display: none;\" name=\"lang\" value=\"" + lang + "\">");

    $('.lang').click(function () {
        $("#lang").remove();
        $("#myForm").append("<input id=\"lang\" type=\"hidden\" style=\"display: none;\" name=\"lang\" value=\"" + $(this)[0].id + "\">");

        loadlang($(this)[0].id);
    });
```

Comment: Are you including the captcha plug-in code?

Comment: `.captcha` sounds like a plugin. Are you including it anywhere?

Comment: Check whether you have included `jquery.captcha.js` file

Comment: yes, i'm including "captcha/jquery.captcha.js". This is the only error i get from Firebug. This is plugin od course. Any idea what's wrong? I tried changing $ to jQuery. Should I insert all of my code here? I don't know is it relevant, but this is asp.net mvc app.

Comment: also if i add   $(".ajax-fc-container").captcha({ outside of loadlang function it works, hovewer not all pictures all loaded, sometging is wrong

Comment: I found solution: asp.net mvc app was adding automatically new jQeury library "jquery-1.7.1.js" and there is a problem with fancy captcha and latest jQuery libraries. So there is no TypeError problem. Hovewer, I can't see 1 picture and the captcha isn't working.